# Unloading a large amount (100,000+) of records from the ember store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a large amount, here being about 100,000 or more records, of a particular type of model in the ember store that I created by passing a JSON object to the store's `createRecord` method. When i try and unload all of these records using `store.unloadAll('record-type')` the records do eventually all end up being fully unloaded from the store, but it takes about 90 seconds for the operation to complete.

What confuses me more is that the `unloadAll` method returns instantly and does not return a promise yet the web GUI will freeze up, and, using the ember inspector I can see all of the records are still present, until after about 90 seconds when they finally disappear.

I am calling the `unloadAll` method from an action as below:

```
    actions: {
        unloadStore() {
            console.log('calling unloadAll');
            this.get('store').unloadAll('record-type');
            console.log('unloadAll returns immediately');
        }
    }
```

And I am creating these models as below:

```
    for(let obj of data.response){
      store.createRecord('record-type', {
        'id':         obj._id.$oid,
        'prop1':      obj.prop1,
        'prop2':      obj.prop2,
        'prop3':      obj.prop3
      });
    }
```

Is it expected that unloading this amount of records should take 80+ seconds or am I doing something wrong? I have noticed through Chrome's performance profiler that a large amount of time is spent in the `removeObject` method of the ember.debug.js file. And I think it has something to do with the repeated firings of the arrayContentWillChange and other such events triggered by changing the record array during `unloadAll`'s execution. A screenshot of the performance profile is linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JUs8.jpg) .

Comment: Did you try to collect id's (using `peekAll` for example) and then call `unloadRecord` in a loop?

Comment: I have adjusted the code to be `store.peekAll('record-type').forEach(function(obj) {...} );` where inside of that loop I collect the ids of each obj. After that I `findRecord` by the id and unload but I am unfortunately still experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: Are you observing this collection elsewhere in the active route hierarchy? e.g. do you have a route `model()` hook returning `findAll('record-type')` somewhere when the `unloadAll('record-type')` occurs?

Comment: The collection is not referenced in any model hooks. They are created in a websocket service and `peekAll` is called on them in one other service and two components. From what I can tell we are not explicitly adding any additional observers other than what might already be built into ember. The models are only ever iterated over via 'peekAll' to have their properties retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
// route.js
actions: {
  reloadModel() {
    this.store.peekAll('my-model').forEach((r) => {
      this.store.unloadRecord(r);
    })
    this.refresh(); // to force a fresh load of data from API
  }
}
```